# Parse function unable to parse string and throwing error in Java

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

Not able to parse the following date. Getting parse exception. Please help in finding error :

```
            String myDate = "2020–03–01 3:15 pm";
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm aa",Locale.ENGLISH);
            Date date = sdf.parse(myDate);
```

Comment: Any message with the exception?

Comment: @karllindmark java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2020–03–01 3:15pm"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The separator character that you have used to separate the year, the month and the day doesn't seem to be correct. I suggest you type the date-time string again instead of copying and pasting it from somewhere. I also recommend you switch from the outdated date-time API to the [modern](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) one.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String myDate = "2020-03-01 3:15 pm";
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                            .parseCaseInsensitive()
                                            .appendPattern("u-M-d h:m a")
                                            .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(myDate, formatter);
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-03-01T15:15
```

If you still want to use the legacy date-time API, you can do it as follows:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String myDate = "2020-03-01 3:15 pm";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm aa", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date date = sdf.parse(myDate);
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Sun Mar 01 15:15:00 GMT 2020
```

Note that I've used a single `h` to match your date-time string.

Comment: getting error : Text '2020-03-01 3:15pm' could not be parsed at index 15

Comment: `2020-03-01 3:15pm` has no space between `15` and `pm` and therefore, you need to use the pattern `yyyy-MM-dd h:mmaa` for this date-time string. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt/issue.

Answer (score 2):

From the looks of it your date string contains `–` (dash) instead of `-` (hyphen).

Try using hyphens in the date instead and see if it manages to parse it correctly.

### Bonus ascii table details:

Dash (`-`):

[image: dash]

.

Hyphen (`-`):

[image: hyphen]

Comment: corrected the character but still....Unparseable date: "2020-03-01 3:15pm"

Comment: @SudhanshuGoyal after fix the character it's working the code you post and your error seems for not use space between `3:15` and `pm`